# Sql query optimization using IN over INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given:

**Table y**

- `id int clustered index`
- `name nvarchar(25)`

**Table anothertable**

- `id int clustered Index`
- `name nvarchar(25)`

**Table someFunction**

- does some math then returns a valid ID

Compare:

```
SELECT y.name
  FROM y
 WHERE dbo.SomeFunction(y.id) IN (SELECT anotherTable.id 
                                    FROM AnotherTable)
```

vs:

```
SELECT y.name 
  FROM y
  JOIN AnotherTable ON dbo.SomeFunction(y.id) ON anotherTable.id
```

**Question:**

While timing these two queries out I found that at large data sets the first query using `IN` is much faster then the second query using an `INNER JOIN`. I do not understand why can someone help explain please.

[Execution Plan](http://www.mediafire.com/file/0o46nmtyha4h8m8/executionPlane.xml)

Comment: Consult the optimizer/explain plan - we can't tell you what is happening with your data.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would guess that it is because in the IN case it gets the list of id's from anotherTable once, whereas in the INNER join it effectively has to prepare the full outer product of the records and check each one. Your function call prevents it from doing any optimisation of its own.

Comment: @OMG Ponies- I noticed this using multiple different datasets. This is a behavior i feel is data agnostic.

Comment: @colin fine.  Seems to make sense, thanks for putting me on a research track.

Comment: @gh9 - The obvious difference is that the `IN` version does a hash join for the semi join and the `JOIN` does a merge join. Can you post the actual plans rather than estimated as would be interesting to see the actual row counts.

Comment: @MartinSmith generating the execution plans again, it will take  awhile to run because data set is very large

Comment: @gh9 - Because of the `GROUP BY` in your actual query the semantics of the query are that they will both return the same results I'm wondering whether the `JOIN` ends up expanding the intermediate number of rows processed only to then get rid of the duplicates a bit later on because of the `GROUP BY`. Even if not will still be useful to see how many rows are going into each operator vs estimated.

Comment: @martinsmith stopped running the query because it was taking up to many system resources

Comment: @martinsmith i guess i will just keep the first query and leave this as an unknown thank you for all the help

Comment: @gh9 - I'll post an answer with a potential explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking `IN` is different from `JOIN` in that a `JOIN` can return additional rows where a row has more than one match in the `JOIN`-ed table.

From your estimated execution plan though it can be seen that in this case the 2 queries are semantically the same

```
SELECT
        A.Col1
        ,dbo.Foo(A.Col1)
        ,MAX(A.Col2)
        FROM A
        WHERE dbo.Foo(A.Col1)  IN (SELECT Col1 FROM B)
    GROUP BY
        A.Col1,
        dbo.Foo(A.Col1)
```

versus

```
SELECT
        A.Col1
        ,dbo.Foo(A.Col1)
        ,MAX(A.Col2)
        FROM A
        JOIN B ON dbo.Foo(A.Col1) = B.Col1
    GROUP BY
        A.Col1,
        dbo.Foo(A.Col1)
```

Even if duplicates are introduced by the `JOIN` then they will be removed by the `GROUP BY` as it only references columns from the left hand table. Additionally these duplicate rows will not alter the result as `MAX(A.Col2)` will not change. This would not be the case for all aggregates however. If you were to use `SUM(A.Col2)` (or `AVG` or `COUNT`) then the presence of the duplicates would change the result.

It seems that SQL Server doesn't have any logic to differentiate between aggregates such as `MAX` and those such as `SUM` and so quite possibly it is expanding out all the duplicates then aggregating them later and simply doing a lot more work.

The estimated number of rows being aggregated is `2893.54` for `IN` vs `28271800` for `JOIN` but these estimates won't necessarily be very reliable as the join predicate is unsargable.

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to explain and bear with me as I was uploading the info. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

Your second query is a bit funny - can you try this one instead??

```
SELECT y.name 
FROM dbo.y
INNER JOIN dbo.AnotherTable a ON a.id = dbo.SomeFunction(y.id)
```

Does that make any difference?

Otherwise: look at the execution plans! And possibly post them here. Without knowing a lot more about your tables (amount and distribution of data etc.) and your system (RAM, disk etc.), it's really really hard to give a "globally" valid statement

Answer (score 2):

Well, for one thing: get rid of the scalar UDF that is implied by `dbo.SomeFunction(y.id)`.  [That will kill your performance real good](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2008/05/23/reuse-your-code-with-cross-apply.aspx).  Even if you replace it with a one-row inline table-valued function it will be better.

As for your actual question, I have found similar results in other situations and have been similarly perplexed.  The optimizer just treats them differently; I'll be interested to see what answers others provide.

Comment: +1 good advice: "the scalar UDF that is implied" -- something I didn't immediately spot ;)